# Replace character of string ignoring whitespaces until a character in java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, split

Having a string like this:

```
"\t\t\t \t \t *words aasdasd\t\t \t"
```

I want to be replacing any \t before the * character ignoring any \t after it to result in:

```
"   *words aasdasd\t\t \t"
```

What is the most elegant way to do so in java. I thought of splitting on * first then replacing \t in the first part then append the splits again.

Comment: that's probably what I would do

Comment: what you suggested in your question.  i'm not a fan of regex.  they're speedy to run, but unless you know regex syntax well .... next time you come accross them you have a new problem.

Comment: true story. And yes i chose it for speed and elegance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
\\t(?=[^*]*\\*)
```

and replace by empty string.

In Java:

```
String string = "\t\t\t \t \t *words aasdasd\t\t \t";
string = string.replaceAll("\\t(?=[^*]*\\*)", "");
System.out.println( string );
//=>    *words aasdasd\t\t \t
```

`(?=[^*]*\\*)` is a lookahead that makes sure there is `*` followed by `\t` for replacement.

Comment: I get "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: it still doesnt work. this worked for me
.replaceAll("\t(?=.*\\*)", "");

Comment: Yes you can also use: `string.replaceAll("\\t(?=.*?\\*)", "");` also but above code is direct copy/paste from Eclipse as well. In Java regex every escape sequence must be **escaped twice**

Comment: isn't the \t a character itself ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "\t\t\t \t \t *words aasdasd\t\t \t";
    test = test.replaceAll("\\t(?=.*?\\*)", "");
    System.out.println("" + test);
}
```

This will use a forward look-ahead to check and see if there is a * after the `\t` if there is it will replace the `\t` with `""`.

Output:

```
`   *words aasdasd\t\t \t`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a non-`regex` approach, using `substring()`, `replaceAll()`, and `replace()` you can accomplish what you're wanting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "\t\t\t \t \t *words aasdasd\t\t \t";
    System.out.println("\"Before: " + data + "\"");

    String substring = data.substring(0, data.indexOf("*"));
    String newSubstring = substring.replaceAll("\\t", "");

    System.out.println("\"After : " + data.replace(substring, newSubstring) + "\"");
}
```

Results:

```
"Before:                     *words aasdasd         "
"After :    *words aasdasd          "
```

Comment: Thanks, That's what I have been trying and achieved myself. I wanted the regex solution.